I use decompyle3 or uncompyle6 It decompiles my functions that do not start with "get" but if my function starts with "get" it generates an error?
I use decompyle3 or uncompyle6
It decompiles my functions that do not start with "get" but if my function or method starts with "get" it generates an error:
def get_list_patientParse error at or near `POP_BLOCK' instruction at offset 120
so my function is get_list_patient(request):
since it starts with "get" it gives this error.
def get_list_patientParse error at or near `POP_BLOCK' instruction at offset 120

Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please include sample code needed to reproduce the error and an exact traceback?

can I send you this .pyc file? if possible I will send it to you by email address
